# Angular update scope with individual values for $watch inside directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Let's say I have two draggable elements

```
<div draggable enabled="false"></div>
<div draggable enabled="false"></div>
```

To enable/disable the elements I use the following directive:

```
App.directive('draggable', function() {
return {
restrict:'A',
link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
    element.draggable();

    scope.$watch('enabled', function (val) {
    element.draggable(val === true ? 'enable' : 'disable');

  });
}
};});
```

I have setup a $watch looking enabled to be true/false.
Now I would like to use my controller to change the 'enabled' property.

```
App.controller('TypeAheadController',function($scope){

//some code
$scope.enabled = true;
});
```

However, when I use this, ALL the draggable elements are referenced. So they all get enabled or disabled. Which I think is strange, as I would expect the $watch to look for the enabled value inside the scope for each draggable element. My goal is to enable/disable the draggable element individually. So I need a way to set/reference the enabled property for each draggable element in the controller.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change the directive to have it's own scope:

```
App.directive('draggable', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        scope: { 
            enabled: '='
        },
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
            element.draggable();

            scope.$watch('enabled', function (val) {
                element.draggable(val === true ? 'enable' : 'disable');

            });
        }
    };
});
```

To have your controller control each individual directive you would need to have a corresponding configuration for each directive:

```
App.controller('TypeAheadController', function ($scope) {
    $scope.draggableItems = [{enabled:true},{enabled: true}];
});
```

and in your HTML:

```
<div ng-repeat="draggable in draggableItems" draggable enabled="draggable.enabled"></div>
```

Comment: How can I access the local scope from outside the directive?
I need to set it inside the controller (like I tried to do with $scope.enabled = true;)

Comment: @Ray I think the underlying issue has to do with the fact that you're tying the enabled property to the Controller's enabled property. If you want to have each directive have it's own `enabled` property you would need to make `enabled` into an array for each directive.

Comment: "you would need to make `enabled` into an array for each directive"
How would you do this? 

If I use the isolated scope in my updated version, I have for each directive a scope. So that's fine, however I have no idea how to reference it from outside the directive. So basically, the question is, how can I set a draggable `enabled` based on a condition that comes from outside the directive.

Comment: @Ray Just updated my response. Please let me know if that makes sense.